# Swift and call C++ function with &int argument

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift

I study how to use C++ with Swift in one project.

I have C++ class with interface

```
class SwypeDetect {
public:
  SwypeDetect();
  void asyncFunction(int &a);
};
```

and implementation

```
SwypeDetect::SwypeDetect() {}

void SwypeDetect::asyncFunction(int &a) {
  a = 1;
  sleep(3);
  a = 10;
  sleep(3);
  a = 100;
}
```

asyncFunction just change value of argument a three time each three seconds. Of course I create Objective-C wrapper

```
@interface Wrapper()
@property (nonatomic, assign) SwypeDetect detector;
@end

@implementation Wrapper

- (instancetype) init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _detector = SwypeDetect();
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)asyncFunction:(int *)a {
  _detector.asyncFunction(*a);
}

@end
```

And then use this wrapper in Swift class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "wrapper queue", attributes:.concurrent)

  var valueA: Int32 = 0 {
    didSet {
      print("new valueA \(valueA) on time \(Date())")
    }
  }

  var detector: Wrapper? {
    didSet {
      if let detector = detector {
        queue.async {
          detector.asyncFunction(&self.valueA)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    detector = Wrapper()
  }
}
```

I expect that didSet block of valueA would be call three times, but in console I see only call with last change of valueA: "new valueA 100 on time 2018-03-26 11:50:18 +0000". What could I do to change this behaviour?

Comment: Swift registers the changed value only on return from `detector.asyncFunction(&self.valueA)`.

Comment: I see that, but how can I observe changes while before return from detector.asyncFunction(&self.valueA)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to say somewhere 'the variable is changed'. You can do it using closures/blocks/lambdas for instance

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "wrapper queue", attributes:.concurrent)

    var valueA: Int32 = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("new valueA \(valueA) on time \(Date())")
        }
    }

    var detector: Wrapper? {
        didSet {
            if let detector = detector {
                queue.async {
                    detector.asyncFunction(&self.valueA) { value in
                        print("iteration value: \(value)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        detector = Wrapper()
    } }
```

**Wrapper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface Wrapper : NSObject
- (instancetype) init;
- (void)asyncFunction:(int *)a progressHandler: (void(^)(int))progressHandler;
@end
```

**Wrapper.mm**

```
#import "Wrapper.h"
#import "SwypeDetect.hpp"

@interface Wrapper()
@property (nonatomic, assign) SwypeDetect detector;
@end

@implementation Wrapper

- (instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _detector = SwypeDetect();
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)asyncFunction:(int *)a progressHandler: (void(^)(int))progressHandler {
    _detector.asyncFunction(*a , progressHandler);
}

@end
```

**SwipeDetect.cpp**

```
#include "SwypeDetect.hpp"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
SwypeDetect::SwypeDetect() {}

void SwypeDetect::asyncFunction(int &a, std::function<void(int)> f) {
    std::cout << "Come up and C++ me some time." << std::endl;
    a = 1;
    f(a);
    sleep(1);
    a = 10;
    f(a);
    sleep(1);
    a = 100;
    f(a);
}
```

**SwypeDetect.hpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>
class SwypeDetect {
public:
    SwypeDetect();
    void asyncFunction(int &a, std::function<void(int)> f);
};
```

**testsetsetset-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "Wrapper.h"
```